# Editing conflicts in browser-based SkyDrive vs. Word application?

Tags: onedrive, collaboration, word-online

When collaborating on documents, I typically use Google Docs as over the years editing conflicts have become very rare.

However, for working on collaborateive `.docx` files, I'm opting to use SkyDrive since formatting and layouts render more consistently.*

I have a feeling that it's best of all users that are simultaneously editing a file do so in their [browser version of SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/).

Or does using the PC version of Word 2010 provide ample conflict resolution and frequent-enough syncing?

<sub>* Not Google's fault, the XML markup of Office files can be extremely convoluted.</sub>